# Visual representation of separated sets.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, visualization

Two subsets $A$ and $B$ of a metric space $X$ are said to be separated if both $A\cap \bar{B}$ and $\bar{A}\cap {B}$ are empty.

My question is that if I take two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of a metric space $X$ then are they separated?

And further for disjoint or any arrangement of sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I can always find a case where $\exists$ an element $e \in (A\cap \bar{B})$ either $e \in (\bar{A}\cap {B})$ . So I'm not able to visualize it in my mind the concept of separated sets, any visual representation in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ would be really helpful.

Comment: Think of the unit ball and its complement. Are they separated?

Comment: Can you provide a visual representation of it?

Comment: Intuitively, the sets are separated if neither contains a limit point or isolated point of the other (a consequence of this is that the sets must be disjoint).
$$ $$
*Aside:* The "tricky" part is the business about limits points. We only have to mention isolated points to ensure the sets don't overlap (if $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$, then certainly $\bar{A}\cap B\neq\varnothing$).
$$ $$
So in $\mathbb R$, the intervals $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$ are separated. But the intervals $[0,1]$ and $(1,2]$ are *not* separated, even though they are disjoint.

Comment: If $A,B$ are separated subsets of a metric space then $A,B$ are completely separated, which means there are disjoint open sets $A',B'$ such that $A\subset A'$ and $B\subset B'.$...  A $T_1$  space $X$ has this property for all subsets $A,B$ iff $X$ is  hereditarily normal, i.e. all the subspaces of $X$ are normal $(T_4)$ spaces. I have seen "completely normal " used for "hereditarily normal". this property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x\geqslant0\}$ and let $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x<0\}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, but they are not separated: for instance, $(0,0)\in A\cap\overline B$ (but $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset$).

Comment: Okay, so disjoint sets doesn't imply that they are separated too but can you give an example of separated sets?

Comment: @SahilSilare Sure: $\{(1,0)\}$ and $\{(0,0)\}$. Do you want me to add this example to my answer?

Comment: Can you please provide a visual representation using sets $A$ and $B$? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @SahilSilare But I provided an example in wich each set consists of a single point! Can't you visualize points?

Comment: Oh okay got the concept! Thank you sir

Comment: @SahilSilare I'm glad I could help.